What is this usage of of double ような?

The context is the following: The character is writing a report of the previous night, however he wants to hide details to his boss, in this case the fact they fought each other (同士打ち) More so, he's also worried she may have caught what actually happened.

そう考えると、やはり三貴子に見透かされているような、

If you think it like that, I feel like 三貴子 has seen through everything but then what does is the second sentence actually mean?
全く関係ないあと処理の話のような。

If you are asking about construction, it is parallelism.

"～(の)ような、～(の)ような" is a common pattern used to express uncertainty, or a situation that could be interpreted in multiple ways.

鳥のような、飛行機のような…。
Um, it was like a bird, or maybe an airplane...
見たような、見ていないような…。
As if I've seen it, as if I haven't...

In this context, the speaker is uncertain whether 三貴子 has already realized the hidden details or is simply discussing an unrelated matter.

やはり三貴子に見透かされているような、全く関係ないあと処理の話のような。
It's as if 三貴子 has seen through everything, yet also as if she's talking about something completely unrelated—the follow-up process.


Oh thank you. あと処理 was confusing me too since I thought it was like あと+ 処理
